# Laravel 5.4 Call to undefined function App\iconv()

Tags: php, iconv

I have uploaded my project to a server, and now it is giving me problems, which can be ?, in local the project runs perfectly. this is the code of my function

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Gateway extends Model
{
     function _doPost($query) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://secure.nmi.com/api/transact.php");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

        if (!($data = curl_exec($ch))) {
            return ERROR;
        }
        $wm_string = iconv("windows-1251", "UTF-8", $data);
        parse_str(urldecode($wm_string), $result);
        $data=json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
        curl_close($ch);
        unset($ch);

        $this->datos=$data;
        return $this->datos;
      } 
       }
```

the error is

**Call to undefined function App\iconv()**
in this line

```
    $wm_string = iconv("windows-1251", "UTF-8", $data);
```

can be this a server problem? or maybe I must to download some package to my project?

Comment: Make sure `iconv` is supported on your pc. What do you have - mac, win, linux?

Comment: the problem appears in the server, in my pc it's work fine, I have windows

Comment: So your server doesn't have `iconv` support.

Comment: ok, then I must to contact with support,I don't have to implement some package to fix this?

Comment: Its a php extension. Do you have root access to the server or is it a shared host?

Comment: Hi kaspar, it doesn't  a shared host, it's a vps host

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to ask your hosting provider to give/install PHP compiled with `iconv`. Because by default `php` comes with `iconv` unless explicitly compiled without it.

> This extension is enabled by default, although it may be disabled by
>   compiling with --without-iconv .

**`iconv:`** http://php.net/manual/en/book.iconv.php

**`iconv installation:`** http://php.net/manual/en/iconv.installation.php